# zend database query limit not working as desired

Tags: mysql, zend-framework

i have a query to read magazine from db as

```
$select = $db->select()
            ->from('tbl_magazine',array('magazine_id','magazine_name'))
            ->join('tbl_magazine_issue','tbl_magazine_issue.magazine_id = tbl_magazine.magazine_id',array(null))
            ->join('mst_publisher','mst_publisher.publisher_id = tbl_magazine.publisher_id',array(null))
            ->where('tbl_magazine.is_active =?',1)
            ->where('mst_publisher.is_active =?',1)
            ->where('tbl_magazine_issue.os_select =?',2)
            ->where('tbl_magazine_issue.publish_status = ?',1)
            ->where('curdate() <= DATE(tbl_magazine.validity_till)')
            ->group('tbl_magazine.magazine_id')
            ->limit($start,$per_page);
```

but when i print the query i see some thing like this

```
SELECT `tbl_magazine`.`magazine_id`, `tbl_magazine`.`magazine_name` 
FROM `tbl_magazine` 
INNER JOIN `tbl_magazine_issue` ON tbl_magazine_issue.magazine_id = tbl_magazine.magazine_id 
INNER JOIN `mst_publisher` ON mst_publisher.publisher_id = tbl_magazine.publisher_id 
WHERE (tbl_magazine.is_active =1) AND (mst_publisher.is_active =1) 
  AND (tbl_magazine_issue.os_select =2) AND (tbl_magazine_issue.publish_status = 1) 
  AND (curdate() <= DATE(tbl_magazine.validity_till)) 
GROUP BY `tbl_magazine`.`magazine_id` 
LIMIT 2147483647 OFFSET 8
```

but i have set $start as 0 and $perpage as 8

i was looking for a query with limit as `"limit 0 ,8"`

Comment: ya when start is set to 0 ,the problem arises otherwise the correct value of start is taken.also i dont need an offset ,i need my query limit like this limit 0,8 so that i can get 8 results on every request.please help

Comment: @Alex so what should i do so as to get limit 0,8 in my query??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you are not using `limit` correctly.

Here is function definition from `Zend_Db_Select`. As you can see 1st param is `count` and not `offset`.

```
/**
 * Sets a limit count and offset to the query.
 *
 * @param int $count OPTIONAL The number of rows to return.
 * @param int $offset OPTIONAL Start returning after this many rows.
 * @return Zend_Db_Select This Zend_Db_Select object.
 */
public function limit($count = null, $offset = null)
{
    $this->_parts[self::LIMIT_COUNT]  = (int) $count;
    $this->_parts[self::LIMIT_OFFSET] = (int) $offset;
    return $this;
}
```

---

And just to explain why you were getting those crazy values... Below is part of script that renders the SQL query. Because you had offset it was setting count to PHP_INT_MAX.

```
 if (!empty($this->_parts[self::LIMIT_OFFSET])) {
        $offset = (int) $this->_parts[self::LIMIT_OFFSET];
        $count = PHP_INT_MAX;
    }
```

Comment: ya thanks now i got u ....the params have to be swapped .one more doubt is the query "limit 8 offeset 0" same as limit 0,8 ??.

Comment: offset is optional and if it is `0` it will not be added. You said before that you do not need it... so simply remove it and have `->limit($count)`

Comment: ok i was just doing some stuff with ajax pagination ,thanks for ur help.